# BigCommerce API - Undefined Resource Property - Banners :: item_id

Tags: bigcommerce

I am working with the BigCommerce API for the Banners resource, but I do not know the usage/definition for one of the properties - specifically: `item_id`

The [usage documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/banners) shows the following as the JSON response:

```
 {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Grand Closing Sale",
    "page": "home_page",
    "content": "Thanks for shopping with us.",
    "date_to": "1393218000",
    "item_id": "0",
    "visible": "0",
    "location": "top",
    "date_from": "1391576400",
    "date_type": "custom",
    "date_created": "1392073898"
  },
```

The [property documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/objects/v2/banner) however makes no reference to `item_id` (and also has other various typos and unlinked properties).

**What is `item_id`?** 
Is it maybe supposed to be `catorbrandid`, which says "ID for the brand or category."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the other various typos and unlinked properties so we can fix them? If you toggle a banner to be assigned to a category or brand, does the item_id field become populated with a value?

Comment: @Alyss Hey, so there's a couple. In the format of `typo = correction`, they are: `dateto = date_to` | `bannerid = id` | `datefrom = date_from` | `datetype = date_type` | `datecreated = date_created` | `catorbrandid = item_id` | `status/visible = visible`. Also, you are correct about the `item_id`! It becomes populated with the value of assigned category or brand. This is problemsome though in that if one were to create a banner via the API, there would be no way to distingquish the link between a category or a brand. Unless, are cat|brand ID's unique? - meaning that they will never share IDs?